# How can i work with DICOM protocol in Mule ESB

Tags: mule, dicom

I install Anypoint studio.
I find https://github.com/neohope/mule-transport-dicom, but i not understand how use this. Anybody can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This project is not usable, it doesn't build a proper Mule connector. It apparently has been started and quickly abandoned, by the look of its [history](https://github.com/neohope/mule-transport-dicom/commits/master).